# How to plot/scatter columns of matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm having a trouble plotting with numpy arrays/matrices. I define a matrix of random numbers as follows:

```
g1 = matrix([[x,y] for x,y in zip(rand(40),rand(40)) if ((x>0.5 and y>0.5) or (x<0.5 and y<0.5))])
```

That creates the appropriate matrix. now I want to scatter this matrix elemnts:

```
scatter(g1[:,1],g1[:,0])
```

That fails with error: `maximum recursion depth exceeded`

It seems the problem is caused by the fact that the column `g1[:,1]` is still a matrix. because if I plot:

```
plot(array(g1[:,1]),array(g1[:,0]))
```

That is working. 
I'm quite confused by how something that intuitive and simple such as plotting a matrix columns one against the other is that complicated. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `scatter(g1[:,1],g1[:,0])` works just fine for me - Python 3.3, matplotlib 1.3.0, numpy 1.8.0...

Comment: This is a known bug https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2290

Comment: Very interesting - I just installed matplotlib 1.3.1, and got the recursion error...

Comment: I'd seriously ask myself whether you need to use matrices. In my (and many other) experience arrays are perfectly fine.

Comment: sorry, pointed you at the wrong PR, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2591

Comment: which is not in 1.3.1

Comment: another workaround seems to be `scatter( g1[:,1].flat, g1[:,0 ].flat )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue which is partially fixed http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2591 (made it into 1.3.1) and fully fixed in http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2591 (not yet in a stable release, but on both `master` and 1.3.x branches.